# re-seq not returning all regex matches

Tags: clojure

I'm using re-seq to get all the sequences that match a regex in clojure like so:

```
(re-seq #"(.*)\&(.*)" "((a & b) & c)")
```

And I'm getting the following result:

```
(["(a&b)&c" "(a&b)" "c"])
```

Whereas I expect the sequence to contain all such regex matches like so:

```
(["(a&b)&c" "(a&b)" "c"] ["(a&b)&c" "(a" "b)&c"])
```

How to fix this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `re-seq` doesn't work that way, as you've seen. After it (greedily) finds a match, it starts looking for the next one "at the first character not matched by the previous match" as explained here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()

Comment: You can use `re-find` https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-find

Answer (score 0):

As Jas alluded to, the star is greedy. In this case the non-greedy star should work (which java calls a "Reluctant Quantifier"): `.*?`

```clj
(re-seq #"(.*?)\&(.*)" "((a&b)&c)")
```

gives

```clj
(["((a&b)&c)" "((a" "b)&c)"])
```

This can be challenging to apply in more complicated situations.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html